# Calculus of Variation - Minimize a Functional

Tags: calculus, optimization, variational-analysis

I am struggling with a basic question from a homework assignment regarding Calculus of Variation. I would love if somebody could get me started in the right direction, as I am pretty lost and the textbook does not cover problems this simple. I have never dealt with Functionals before, so I am a little short on intuition. Here is the problem:



We consider the functional $F:X\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$F(y)=\int_{0}^1 (y(x)^2-1)^2dx$$
Find the minimum and all the minimizers of the functional $F$ over the set $X$ in the following cases:

a. $X=\{\text{continuous functions}\ y: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}\}$

b. $X=\{\text{continuous functions}\ y: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R} \; \text{such that} \; y(0)=1\}$



In short, I really don't know where to start. I looked online, and it seems like most of these types of problems are supposed to be solved using Euler's formula or some other method. However, my professor has not introduced any formulas or any explicit method that we can use to solve such a problem.

The professor has only given us one similar example in whiched he solved $F(y)=\int_{0}^1 (y(x)-1)^2dx$ instead of the above problem. However, he solved it by simply claiming that $F$ has a minimum of $0$, and then proving that. He did not show us how he determined the minimum in the first place.

Any tips in the right direction would be very helpful. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter the what the function $y$ is, the function $(y^2(t)-1)^2$ is always nonnegative, so the smallest that $$F(y)=\int_0^1 (y^2(t)-1)^2\,dt$$ could possibly be is zero. Is there any continuous function $y:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ which makes $F(y)$ equal to zero? If so, then there is your answer to part (a). For any of the answer(s) to part(a), does $y(0)=1$? If so, then there is your answer to (b) as well.

Comment: Thank you Alex! I think I'm on the right track...I know that the function $z:=(y^2 (t) - 1)^2$ must be zero in order to make $F(y)=0$. And $z=0$ when $t= \pm 1$. Am I correct in thinking that these two answers for $t$ would be solutions for part (a)? But only $t=0$ would be a solution for (b) since $y(0)=1$?

Comment: I agree you are on the right track here. What is $z$? Also, why are you trying to find values for $t$? $t$ is a variable used in the integral. You are trying to find $y$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: Okay so I was thinking that the minimizers would be values of $t$. Would that be wrong? Are the minimizers here actually the different functions $y(t)$ such that $F(y)=0$?

Comment: Yes that is wrong, and yes, the minimizers are functions $y(t)$ which, when plugged into the integral, make the integral $0$. Calculus of variantions differs from single variable and multivariable in that the minimizers and maximizers in optimization problems are not merely points or vectors, but entire functions!

Comment: Ah I think I get it! So the correct answers for part (a) would be the two constant functions $y(t)=\pm 1$, but the added condition for part (b) leaves only the solution of $y(t)=1$?

Comment: Very good.$\quad$

Answer (score 2):

If $F \geq 0$ on $\Omega$, then $\int_{\Omega}F \geq 0$ and $\int_{\Omega}F = 0 \Leftrightarrow F\equiv 0$. Hence, $\int_{\Omega}F$ has a global minimum of $0$ when $F\equiv 0$ (except for countably many points, but if $F$ is continuous then this can't happen).

In regards to the difference between the two sets, notice that the second one implies that $y>0$ for some $x\in [0,1]$. In this case, it implies that the integrand is $0$ at that point, which means that $y \equiv 1$ is the only minimizer. For the first set, however, we could *also* have $y \equiv -1$.

In the hypothetical case where the integrand was just $y^2$, these two sets' differences are highlighted. The first set would simply have the solution $y\equiv 0$, as expected. However, the second set has that $y>0$ for some $x\in [0,1]$. Since $y$ is continuous, $\int_{[0,1]}y^2 > 0$ (note the strict inequality). This is a fact worth proving on your own. This means that there is actually no minimum (also worth proving), though the infimum is $0$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering me!
So you're saying that since the function in the integrand, $F$, is $\ge 0$, the minimum of the functional must be zero?

Comment: Also, if you might be able to elaborate on the distinction between parts (a) and (b), that would be awesome! Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. Consider that integral is the area under a curve, and if F is a positive curve then the area must be positive. The smallest that area can be is nothing, since it will never have a negative area.

Comment: Yes give me one moment to add that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer! That is very helpful.